# Как найти синтаксическую ошибку JSON?

Tags: php, json

В php создаю JSON строку из массива `json_encode`.
Получается такой текст.
[Текст JSON](https://pastecode.io/s/s32zgtnd)

При попытки его декодировать `json_decode` выдает `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`. Не могу понять что не такс этим JSON.

Comment: Вполне может быть что у вас проблемы с [BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351165/php-json-decode-json-error-syntax)

Comment: Не знаю что случилось, но ошибки больше нет именно с этим JSON.... Это плохо, не могу понять в чем проблема